Не выводятся записи со страпи
В чем может быть причина того что не появляются данные со страпи?
При локальном запуске 'npm run dev' все записи выводятся, но как только я начинаю деплоить его на Vercel или Netlify и добавляю данные из файла .env
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_TOKEN="токен"
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL="http://'ip':1337"
То все сразу перестает отображаться?

Я решил проблему, она заключалась в том, что мой сервер с админкой запущен на протоколе HTTP, и, соответственно, браузер считает мои выходные данные небезопасным контентом.
Как я понял, тут нужен SSL-сертификат.
